# Localization not working in jQuery UI datePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have performed several modifications to the UI of a web application I am maintaining. These include fetching JS libraries from NuGet and aligning them to a more recent version than the previous.

The old version, running jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.24 (customized, minified, re-beautified by Firebug and [shown to you](http://pastebin.com/KY4uSVMs)) runs a perfectly localized `DatePicker`, including format `dd/MM/yyyy` which is the format of data wired into the text boxes by MVC pages.

Now I have fetched jQuery 1.11.2 and jQuery UI 1.11.2, presuming that everything will continue to work as expected.

Nope.

The DatePicker are still initialized as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.extend({ showMonthAfterYear: false }, $.datepicker.regional['']));
            $(".datePicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['it']);
            $('.datePicker').datepicker('option', 'changeMonth', true);
            $('.datePicker').datepicker('option', 'changeYear', true);
            $("#locale").change(function() {
                $('.datePicker').datepicker('option', $.extend({ showMonthAfterYear: false },
                    $.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()]));
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the textboxes are

```
<input type="text" class="datePicker" id="date_begin" name="pDateBegin" value="<%=Some.Data %>" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="text" class="datePicker" id="date_end" name="pDateEnd" value="<%=Some.Data %>" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Briefly, the old application shows a well-localized calendar and accepts `dd/MM/yyyy` dates. The new refactored application doesn't obviously accept dates as `24/02/2015` as valid dates, leaving the textbox blank. And that version shows an English localized calendar while the JS code requires `it` regional. From Firebug console on the old application I can see the value of `$.datepicker.regional['it']` correctly, and it's empty in the new application.

**I wanted to track down**, to solve the problem myself, where in the code the IT regional is defined, but searching for `Chiudi` (it message for "Close") doesn't find anything. It looks like the language comes from the mistery.

The old application includes the following files (in Firebug's order):

- jquery.form.js
- jquery-1.8.2-min.js
- jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js (linked in the paste, no result for the magic word Chiudi)
- superfish.js
- Custom app's JS scripts (included in the new application and not overriding datepicker anyway)
- MicrosoftAjax.js
- MicrosoftMVC.js
- jquery.tablesorter.js
- jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

An override of datepicker's regional is not even found in the ASPX code, which I haven't changed yet in the page I'm examining.

#### The question is

How to add languages to the standard NuGet distribution of [jQuery UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/)?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization - Check it out this demo & you can download language file from here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js">
</script>
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization - Check it out this demo & you can download language file from here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Comment: That's great. What I didn't tell is that I can't use a CDN on this project only because the app (may) run at a *large-american-bank-that-has-been-recently-hacked-leaking-personal-data* xD with workstations behind heavy firewalling/proxying, but the answer is OK for the general case. One could actually both install the NuGet package (below) and use Web Optimization to add a CDN reference too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as usual I find the answer by myself after 12 seconds from posting the question on SO.

```
Install-Package jQuery.UI.i18n
```

The package doesn't appear on top of the list and I had to search for `Tags:"jQueryUI" i18n` to find it

Next step was to modify (for me that I use Web Optimization)

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"));
```